# Why are results ordered in this Task.parSequenceUnordered? Monix

Tags: scala, monix

Because Task.parSequenceUnordered "[is like parSequence, except that you don’t get ordering for results or effects.](https://monix.io/docs/3x/eval/task.html#taskunit:%7E:text=Task.parSequenceUnordered%20is%20like%20parSequence%2C%20except%20that%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20get%20ordering%20for%20results%20or%20effects.)", I would expect the following to return List(2, 1):

```
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global


object TaskSequence extends App {

    val taskOne = Task {
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      println("First executed")
      1
    }
    val taskTwo = Task {
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      println("Second executed")
      2
    }
  
    val parallelUnordered = Task.parSequenceUnordered(List(taskOne, taskTwo)).runSyncUnsafe()
    println(s"Return vals for Task.parSequenceUnordered( ) were $parallelUnordered")
}
```

However, I get List(1, 2) as a result. Using .runAsync( ) doesn't make a difference either:

```
    Task.parSequenceUnordered(List(taskOne, taskTwo)).runAsync( result => result match {
      case Right(value) => println(value)
      case Left(value) => value
    })
  Thread.sleep(5000) // don't let program exit
```

The second Task finishes first, so I should get the 2 back first in the return List, right? Can any Monix experts weigh in? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the [implementation](https://github.com/monix/monix/blob/series/4.x/monix-eval/shared/src/main/scala/monix/eval/internal/TaskParSequenceUnordered.scala#L180) of `parSequenceUnordered`, which builds the result list by using O(1) prepend operations.

There's a

```scala
private sealed abstract class State[+A] {
  def isActive: Boolean
  def enqueue[B >: A](value: B): State[B]
}
```

to represent the internal state machine for the task, and a couple of the State subclasses look like

```
final case class Active[+A](list: List[A], remaining: Int) extends State[A] {

  def isActive = true
  def enqueue[B >: A](value: B): Active[B] =
    Active(value :: list, remaining - 1)
}
```

So because it uses `value :: list` to accumulate the results, they are built in reverse in terms of which result comes in first.

Answer (score 0):

An experiment with more Tasks:

```
    val taskOne = Task {
      Thread.sleep(4000)
      println("First executed")
      1
    }
    val taskTwo = Task {
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      println("Second executed")
      2
    }
    val taskThree = Task {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println("Third executed")
      3
    }
    val taskFour = Task {
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      println("Fourth executed")
      4
    }

    Task.parSequenceUnordered(List(taskOne, taskTwo, taskThree, taskFour)).runAsync( result => result match {
      case Right(value) => println(value)
      case Left(value) => value
    }
```

Resulted in:

```
Second executed
Third executed
First executed
Fourth executed
List(4, 1, 3, 2)
```

This shows that the results are returned in **opposite order** when using `Task.parSequenceUnordered( )`, from last completed to first completed.